Why I cannot access cookies in middleware in Nextjs
I have a middleware sitting between the client and /api/Blog/[id]/route.js async function GET(){...}

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import authenticate from "./middlewares/authenticate";
import { verifyToken } from "./lib/token";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const { method, nextUrl } = req;

  //GET Blog api
  if (nextUrl.pathname.match(/^\/api\/Blog\/.*/) && method === "GET") {
    const cookie = await cookies();
    console.log(cookie); //ResponseCookies {}

    const cookie2 = req.cookies;
    console.log(cookie2); //RequestCookies {}

  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/Blog/:path", "/Blog/:path"],
};


The cookies are empty when i try to access them in middleware, but they are fine when i access them from the server /api/Blog. Does this have to do with the edgetime runtime middleware runs in? But I have other middlewares that can access cookies just fine.
